# ImportError when importing beautifulsoup

Tags: python

When I try to import `beautifulsoup` with the code below in Python 3.0 in Eclipse I get the Error `ImportError: No module named 'bs4'`. However, when I run the code in my IPython Notebook I don't receive an Error and when I try to install it again in the Command Prompt I get the message `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)`. I don't know how to resolve this.

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
```

**Edit**: Downloaded Python 3.4.3 and having the same issues as described above.

Comment: you are running IPython on Python3 as well?

Comment: @FixIncome which python plugin are you using in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The line should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Capitalization is important in Python. If you're using an old version of BeautifulSoup (which you shouldn't be), it's:

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thanks. But the Capitilization resulted in the same error and the `import BeautifulSoup` resulted in `ImportError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'` .

Comment: @FixIncome you probably have more than one version of Python installed on your system, and are using one version with IPython and another in Eclipse.

Comment: I do. I have Python 2.7 and 3.0. But, when I run this code in Python 3.0 or 2.7 in Eclipse it results in the Errors. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @FixIncome are you seriously using Python **3.0**? If so, you shouldn't be. Really. 3.0 had serious issues, which is why 3.1 was released only a few months later. The most recent stable version of Python 3 is [3.4.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/), which I ***highly*** recommend using.

Comment: Thank you. I shall download it immediately and get back to you.

Comment: I still get the same issues after running that line of Code in `Python 3.4.3`.